# adding the second path to excludePathPattern is not valid (springboot Interceptors)

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
   registry.addInterceptor(sessionInterceptor)
     .addPathPatterns("/file/**")
     .excludePathPatterns("/file/show/*","file/download/*")
     .addPathPatterns("/*_admin");

}
```

as you can see, '`/file/download/*`' is not valid, but '`/file/show/*`' is valid. help me please, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the exclude patterns into your InterceptorRegistration as a [List](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/InterceptorRegistration.html#excludePathPatterns-java.util.List-):

```
registry.addInterceptor(sessionInterceptor).
            addPathPatterns("/file/**").excludePathPatterns(Arrays.asList("/file/show/*","file/download/*"))
            .addPathPatterns("/*_admin");
```

Comment: it doesn‘t work, ’/file/download/*‘ is still intercepted

Comment: this is really strange，why is the first pattern valid

Comment: Hey @super, what is the full path of the route being intercepted?

Comment: full path? localhost:8080/file/**? for example, localhost:8080/file/delete/{id}